# Updating Cordova / Phonegap based app via the App Store "crashes"

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, app-store

We released a version of our Cordova based app to iTunes, Apple approved it and everything worked extremely well.

After developing some UI improvements, we decided to release an update to the app, which Apple approved again.

Now we have a serious issue. **If a user upgrades from the first version to the second, no JavaScript seems to be executed on initial launch(!)** leaving the user with a blank page (fully closing and re-opening the app does correct the problem, but users struggle with this, despite instructions in our app description). Everything is fine the second time it is opened!

If a user does a fresh install everything is fine first time.

This ONLY occurs when updating from the app store and we are unable to replicate locally / deploying via xcode.

My initial thought is that the "deviceready" event isn't firing. I am testing this theory with Apple at the moment.

Any other suggestions or help would be much appreciated as this is a serious live issue for us.

Comment: It is window.openDatabase that is blowing up (that is done right after deviceready). Trying to come up with a way to handle this. It could be related to the Cordova websqlite backup code.

Answer (score 0):

Bug in iOS > 5.1 and Cordova < 1.7: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-347